# Объявление глобальной переменной внутри функции

Tags: c, объявление, global-variables

Возможно ли объявить глобальную переменную в функции? Если да, то как?

Comment: да, можно, но она будет доступна только в пределах этой функции.

Comment: "Глобальная переменная" - неформальный термин с массой вариаций значения. В большинстве контекстов всем "и так понятно" о чем именно идет речь. А вот в рамках такого вопроса-однострочника, не сопровождаемого никаким контекстом, не мешало бы и уточнить более детально, что вы имеете в виду под "объявить глобальную переменную".

Comment: Вероятно, [нельзя](http://ideone.com/DxeV3g). Но это если я правильно понял суть вопроса.

Comment: @AnT к примеру я обьявил в функцие переменную number
в другой функцие модифицировал/использовал и тд. Тоесть переменная будет сформирована в одной функцие но использовать можно везде
К примеру я создал массив н-елементов
и вместо того чтоб в функцие arr_sort в аргументах вновь указивать н, можна било уже в цикле использовать ету н, которая била сформирована в main.(сори за русский, я украинец)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Объявить глобальную переменную в функции, то есть переменную с внешним или внутренним связыванием, можно. А, вот, определить такую переменную нельзя, так как глобальная переменная - это переменная определенная вне функции.

Например,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;

void f( int i )
{
    extern int x;
    x = i;
}   


int main(void) 
{
    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
    f( 10 );
    printf( "x = %d\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
x = 0
x = 10
```

В этой программе в функции `f` объявляется глобальная переменная `x`

```
extern int x;
```

Answer (score 3):

Объявить или определить?
Возможно, я несколько путаюсь в терминологии, тогда пусть меня поправят, но если я правильно понимаю, то

```
int x = 5;  // Определение глобальной переменной


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    extern int x;     // Ее объявление, локальное для функции main()
    printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

Более того, они могут находиться в разных файлах.

Comment: Обращаю внимание, что это объявление в плане видимости, но не создание глобальной переменной - она всё равно должна быть объявлена где-то ещё.

Comment: @Qwertiy Скорее, определена?

Comment: Да, точно. Опять в терминологии запутался)

Answer (score 2):

Нет, невозможно.

Всё, что объявлено в функции, видно только в ней. Это основной принцип структурного программирования, называющийся «область видимости».

Возможностью межпроцедурного доступа обладают только глобальные переменные. Крайне желательно использовать `static`-переменные, уровня `.c`-файла, но в крайнем случае допустимо использовать и действительно глобальные переменные, уровня всей программы.

*Разумеется, можно:*

1. *Приписать к локальной переменной модификатор `static`, тогда она переживёт выход из функции в силу особого смысла этого ключевого слова при локальных переменных;*
2. *Вернуть из функции указатель на эту переменную.*
3. *Передать этот указатель внутрь другой функции, которая сохранит его внутри своей статической локальной переменной.*

*И это будет работать, так как статические локальные переменные хранятся не на стеке. Однако лучше переместить эту переменную в структуру, как бы хранящую состояние между вызовами, и передавать эту структуру обеим функциям по указателю. Тогда:*

1. *Первая функция будет записывать данные в экземпляр структуры (инициализировать её);*
2. *Вторая функция будет просто читать и писать в эту структуру.*

*Чтобы посторонние не могли вмешаться в массив, воспользуйтесь шаблоном проектирования «прозрачный указатель»: вынесите обе функции и определение структуры в отдельный `.c`-файл, а остальной программе предоставьте прототипы функций и краткого определения структуры, достаточного для объявления указателей на неё (`typedef struct MyStruct;`).*

*Заметьте, **в любом случае придётся что-то передавать в качестве параметра второй функции**.*

Answer (score 1):

Читаем АВТОРОВ языка:

> Объекты, объявляемые вне всех блоков на одном уровне с определениями
>   функций, всегда статические, и они становятся глобальными для всей
>   программы.

"Язык программирования Си" - 
Брайан В. Керниган, Деннис М. Ритчи